# Conditionally disable a submit button ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a reusable form component which has a `validate` and `renderButton` functions. I want to add logic to my `renderButton` function so that the disabled property only applies if the form component is new i.e disabled button should not apply on editing a form. Here my validate function

```
validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options);
    if (!error) return null;
    const errors = {};

    for (let item of error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };
```

Render button function

```
renderButton(label) {
    return (
      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled={this.validate()}>
        {label}
      </button>
    );
  }

Could anyone help me please
```

Comment: You're returning an object from `validate`. How do you expect that to be converted to a disabled boolean? You could try checking its length? `disabled={Object.keys(this.validate()).length === 0}` to see that it returned no errors?